# What are the differences of using service pattern and using standalone repository Spring Data REST?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

What are the differences of using Spring Data REST repository alone and implementing the “service” pattern around it (that is `ItemService`, `ItemServiceImpl` and so on)?

At the first glance the functionality is more or less the same with the difference that the service approach allows for a better customization but it also produces loads of boilerplate code (the implementation and the controller). Here is [an example](https://github.com/odrotbohm/spring-restbucks/tree/master/server/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment) (look `Payment` and `CreditCard` entities) of using both approaches - RESTBucks of Oliver Drotbohm.

The payment abstraction there uses the "service" pattern used (PaymentService, PaymentImpl and then PaymentController with all methods in web folder) while the orders are exposed via Spring Data REST directly.

Comment: I'd love to get this question reopened as I am the author of the code sample the question is about. I think the question is a great one and I would like to answer it. It's not lacking any kind of context to provide a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### tl;dr

The payment functionality lives at a higher level of abstraction as it doesn't follow established HTTP resource patterns (collection resource, item resource, in general: the ones described [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/restful-web-apis/9781449359713/)) and thus warrants a custom service implementation. In contrast, the lifecycle of the order aggregate does indeed follow those patterns and thus doesn't need anything but Spring Data REST exposure plus a few customizations. Find a conceptual overview about how the two implementation parts relate to each other [here](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/ddd-and-rest-domain-driven-apis-for-the-web-5?slide=78).

### Details

That's a great question. The sample application is designed to showcase how different parts of an API can be driven by different requirements and how you can use Spring Data REST to take care of the parts that follow established patterns but at the same time augment it with higher level aspects that are needed to express business processes.

The application is split into two major parts: the order handling that's centered around the `Order` aggregate that is taken through different stages. A conceptual overview about those can be found [here](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/ddd-and-rest-domain-driven-apis-for-the-web-5?slide=61). So parts of our API for the orders will be following standard patterns: filterable collection resources to see all orders, add new orders etc. This is where Spring Data REST shines.

The payment part is different. It somehow needs to blend into both the URI and functional space of the order handling. We achieve that by the following steps:

1. We implement the required functionality in a [dedicated service](https://github.com/odrotbohm/spring-restbucks/blob/7b0854af43e30b61316aec68cf450291850c501e/server/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment/PaymentServiceImpl.java). The repository interaction doesn't match the necessary level of abstraction as we have to verify business constraints on both the `Order` and `Payment` aggregates. That logic needs to live somewhere: in the service.
2. We expose that functionality via [a Spring MVC controller](https://github.com/odrotbohm/spring-restbucks/blob/7b0854af43e30b61316aec68cf450291850c501e/server/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment/web/PaymentController.java) as we (currently) don't need standard patterns like listing all payments. Remember, the example is centered around modeling the ordering process, it's not an accounting backend. The payment resources are blended into the URI space of the orders: `/orders/{id}/payment`.
3. We use hypermedia elements to indicate when the functionality can be triggered by [adding a link](https://github.com/odrotbohm/spring-restbucks/blob/7b0854af43e30b61316aec68cf450291850c501e/server/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment/web/PaymentOrderModelProcessor.java) pointing to those resources conditionally so that clients can use the presence or absence of those elements to decide what UI affordances to offer to trigger that functionality.

Here's what I think is nice about this approach:

1. You only manually code the parts that are important from the business point of view. No need to implement a lot of boilerplate code for the parts of the API that follow well established patterns.
2. Clients don't need to care where exactly that seam is. Using hypermedia elements, the API just looks like one thing to the client. The server could even move the payment resources to a different URI space or a different service even.

### Resources

[This deck](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/ddd-and-rest-domain-driven-apis-for-the-web-5) discusses what I described in detail. Here's a [video recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdZqeAAIHzc) of it. If you're interested in the higher level ideas of especially the drive towards hypermedia, I suggest [this slide deck](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/rest-beyond-the-obvious-api-design-for-ever-evolving-systems), too

Answer (score 1):

Your service contains all the logic, but the repository layer is as stupid as possible. Its task is a specific operation(for ex. save, edit).

Spring Data is an additional convenient mechanism for interacting with database entities, organizing them in a repository, extracting data, changing it. in some cases, it will be enough to declare the interface and method in it, without implementing it.
P.S
and it's a good choice if you're creating a simple crud